# How do I remove the border around a text box for a SmartGWT SelectItem when exporting to PDF?

Tags: java, textbox, styles, export, smartgwt

SmartClient Version: v9.0p_2014-02-13/EVAL Deployment

Firefox 26.0

When exporting a form to PDF, the printTextBoxStyle for a SelectItem is ignored.

I have a form containing a TextItem, a SelectItem, and a TextAreaItem.

For each FormItem, I call

```
formItem.setPrintTextBoxStyle("printTextBoxStyle")
```

This "printTextBoxStyle" hides the border around the text box.

```
/* PrintStyle.css */
.printTextBoxStyle {
    border-style: none;
}
```

PrintStyle.css is an extra stylesheet defined in my server.properties.

In the exported PDF, the style is applied to the TextItem and TextAreaItem, but the SelectItem always has a border still.

I've tried changing my .printTextBoxStyle to something more obvious as a test, like color:green. When I do that, the text color inside the text boxes for the TextItem and TextAreaItem changes to green. The style for the SelectItem text box always remains the same -- black text with a border around it. It always looks the same for all the CSS properties I've tried.

This leads me to believe that there is something different about SelectItems when it comes to print style. How do I remove the border around a text box for a SelectItem when exporting to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SmartGWT and has been resolved in the latest nightly build as of 2014-03-03.

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=116928

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with adding the argument `!important` to the css property border-style. The goal is to impose your style...

Comment: Does not solve the problem. No matter what CSS rules I put inside .printTextBoxStyle, they are not applied to the SelectItem.